# Can Kubernetes Service control traffic percentage to a given pod?

Tags: kubernetes, service

Is it possible to control the percentage of traffic going to a particular pod with Kubernetes Service, without controlling the number of underlying pod? By default, kube- chooses a backend via a round-robin algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, possible with the **extra** configuration of **Service mesh**.

If you looking forward to do it using the simple service it's hard to do it based on **%** as the default behavior is **round-robin**.

For example, if you are using the **Istio service mesh**

You can route the traffic based on **weight**

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: VirtualService
...
spec:
  hosts:
  - reviews
  http:
  - route:
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v1
      weight: 50
    - destination:
        host: reviews
        subset: v3
      weight: 50
```

where **subset** you can consider is more like the **label** so you are running the deployments with multiple **labels** and do the routing based on **weight** using the **Istio**.

See the [example](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/traffic-shifting/).

Comment: Thank you guys for the reply, i wish Kubernetes service also provides this feature in future.